# Json Connection strings - IConfiguration .net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, configuration, environment-variables

I'm trying to access a connection stored in the application. My solution has two projects, on the one hand, the database project (DAL) and on the other, the WEB API.

On the web api I have an App.settings with the connection string for the two environments.

I'm trying to configure DBContext to take the connection string from there.

What am I doing wrong?

DAL PROJECT:

DBContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using DAL.Models.ProcedureModels;
using DAL;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

..........

       public DBContext()
        {
        }

        public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

.........
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfiguration configuration;
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("local"));
            }
        }
```

JSON FILE IN WEB API PROJECT:

```
{
  "ConectionStrings": {
    "local": "............",
    "staging": "..........",
    "staging_ashure": "",
    "production": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IConfiguration configuration;
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("local"));
```

This declares a variable `configuration` which is uninitialized and as such contains no value, and then immediately attempts to use it. This will not work. You would have to initialize the `configuration` variable first.

But that won’t really help you as you need to actually get the configuration from the web application here.

Instead of using `OnConfiguring`, I would suggest you to just use the constructor with the `DbContextOptions` and then rely on the application to properly register the database context from your library.

So inside of the `ConfigureServices` of your web application’s `Startup`, add this:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("local"));
});
```

There, `DBContext` then would be the type from your `DAL` project.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on accessing connectionstring in `DBContext`, you could try to resolve `IConfiguration` from Service Collection.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(options)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("local");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("local"));
        }
    }
}
```